# I am getting an error

Tags: oracle11g

When I run the query below, I am getting an error.

```
SELECT 'EMP_ID'||','||'LAST_NAME'||','||'FIRST_NAME'||','||'SALARY'
   FROM DUAL
   UNION ALL
   SELECT EMP_ID,LAST_NAME,FIRST_NAME,SALARY
   FROM EMPLOYEES
   ORDER BY  EMP_ID,LAST_NAME,FIRST_NAME;
```

error message:

> "EMP_ID": invalid identifier

What I am trying to here is to create a header with comma

Comment: Normally it's a good idea to tell us **what** error you get, though I can guess in this case.

Answer (score 0):

When you use UNION or UNION ALL, the number of columns selected on each side of UNION / UNION ALL must be the same.

In your example you are selecting 1 column in the first query (the concatenation of 4 strings), and 4 in the second - hence the error.

Comment: I got that Tony, what I am doing here creating CSV file which will have header all the column in select list  but it works only without order by clause.

Comment: @sohel - there are specialized tools for that, why are you trying to do it by hand? It takes far less time to learn the proper tools than it takes to fix such naive approaches.

Answer (score 0):

You got a few issues.

When you do this, it forms a single column.

```
'EMP_ID'||','||'LAST_NAME'||','||'FIRST_NAME'||','||'SALARY'
```

Then you're trying to union 4 columns - both select statements have to have the same number of columns in a union.

The query below will work, because now it's the same #1 of columns just 1

```
 SELECT 'EMP_ID'||','||'LAST_NAME'||','||'FIRST_NAME'||','||'SALARY' 
   FROM DUAL
   UNION ALL
   SELECT EMP_ID || ',' || LAST_NAME || ',' || FIRST_NAME || ',' ||SALARY
   FROM (Select * from EMPLOYEES order by EMP_ID,LAST_NAME,FIRST_NAME) e1;
```

Based on the error you got, make sure you have a columns called "EMP_ID" in your employees table. You would also have to drop the order by column, because they need to be present in the select which it's not.

Comment: Hi Henry, your query is working but I want to add order by clause example :SELECT 'EMP_ID'||','||'LAST_NAME'||','||'FIRST_NAME'||','||'SALARY' 
   FROM DUAL
   UNION ALL
   SELECT EMP_ID || ',' || LAST_NAME || ',' || FIRST_NAME || ',' ||SALARY
   FROM EMPLOYEES
   ORDER BY EMP_ID,LAST_NAME,FIRST_NAME;

Comment: I modified the query to presort it, so it comes out in the order you're looking for. I really don't recommend doing things this way, but It will produce the result you're looking for.